# Pygame Collidepoint Function Not Working As Desired

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, pygame, collision-detection

I am writing a duel-player tank game with Python's PyGame and have completed it for the most part. To give some background into my work, the game involves two tanks that can shoot projectiles at one another, and once one is hit, the other player gains a point. The process continues until one player reaches 10 points, upon which they are declared the winner and the game and timer resets.

My issues occur now that I've drawn a maze to the screen to complement the game and add some more inventiveness. I'm running into one fundamental problem. The Pygame `.collidepoint` is not functioning as it is supposed to. I've intended to make it so that each time a bullet from either tank hits a maze wall, it should disappear as the walls are meant to be impenetrable. Yet the function is arbitrarily choosing whether or not the bullet disappears upon contact - as I wish it to be - or continues through - as I do not want it to. Does anyone know why this could be happening? I've come to assume it has something to do with the `.collidepoint`'s interpretation of coordinates and I've tested around with that but with no success. Is there a better way or function to go about this? If one could tell me if the issue is where I believe it to be and tell me how/give me the little snippet of adjusted code to resolve it, that would be much appreciated. My entire code is pretty long so I just included the code I think is necessary to provide enough information about what I am doing.

I will still, however, clearly emphasize the parts I am having issues with large, explicit blocks made out of comments surrounding the parts of the code. If some more code is needed for context, please let me know and I can provide it.

```
import pygame
import random
import time 

pygame.init()

screenWidth = 700
screenHeight = 700

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenWidth,screenHeight))            
#---------------------------------------------------------#

#Very important function, moves tanks/bullets appropriately, keeps time and score.
def redraw():
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    #DRAW SPRITES TO SCREEN
    tank.draw(screen)
    tank2.draw(screen)
    global barrier 
    barrier = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((100,0),(5,150)))
    global barrier2 
    barrier2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((0,40), (50, 5))) 
    global barrier3 
    barrier3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((50, 120), (50, 5)))
    global barrier4
    barrier4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, pygame.Rect((100, 150), (100,5)))

    global barrier5
    barrier5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((0,175),(50,5)))
    global barrier6
    barrier6 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((150, 100),(5, 50)))
    global barrier7
    barrier7 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((150, 50), (550,5)))
    global barrier8
    barrier8 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, pygame.Rect((50,175),(5,50)))
    global barrier9
    barrier9 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, pygame.Rect((50,225),(100,5)))
    global barrier10
    barrier10 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((200,50),(5,50)))    
    global barrier11
    barrier11 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((375,100),(50,5)))
    global barrier12
    barrier12 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((375,150),(50,5)))    
    global barrier13
    barrier13 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((375,100),(5,50)))   
    global barrier14
    barrier14 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((75, 500),(350,5)))
    global barrier15
    barrier15 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((250, 225),(5,200)))
    global barrier16
    barrier16 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((150,225),(5,200)))
    global barrier17
    barrier17 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((350,225),(5,200))) 
    global barrier18
    barrier18 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((350,425),(200,5)))
    global barrier19
    barrier19 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((550,425),(5,75)))
    global barrier20
    barrier20 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((625,225),(5,325)))
    global barrier21
    barrier21 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((380,550),(250,5)))
    global barrier22
    barrier22 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((305,625),(325,5)))
    global barrier23
    barrier23 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((305,550),(5,75)))
    global barrier24
    barrier24 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((230, 550),(75,5)))
    global barrier25
    barrier25 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((230,550),(5,75)))
    global barrier26
    barrier26 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((160,625),(75,5)))
    global barrier27
    barrier27 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((160,625),(5,75)))
    global barrier28
    barrier28 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((50,575),(5,50)))
    global barrier29
    barrier29 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((50,575),(65,5)))
    global barrier30
    barrier30 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((70,420),(5,155)))
    global barrier31
    barrier31 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((0,500),(30,5)))
    global barrier32
    barrier32 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((45,420),(30,5)))
    global barrier33
    barrier33 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((430,225), (200,5)))
    global barrier34
    barrier34 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((530,125),(5,100)))
    global barrier35
    barrier35 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,pygame.Rect((625,175),(75,5)))
    global barrier36
    barrier36 = pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, pygame.Rect((650,200),(50,5)))
    #Draw bullets to screen
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(screen)
    for bullet in bullets2:
        bullet.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()



while run:

    if hCounter1 < 10 and hCounter2 < 10:
        clock.tick(30)

        previous = passedTime
        passedTime = round(time.time() - begin,2)
        timer = timer + passedTime - previous  

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:            
                if event.key == pygame.K_m: #to shoot projectiles
                    px, py = round(tank.x + tank.width // 2), round(tank.y + tank.height // 2)
                    if len(bullets) < 1:
                        bullets.append(projectile(px, py, 4, (255,255,255), direction))
                if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                    px2, py2 = round(tank2.x + tank2.width // 1.7), round(tank2.y + tank2.height // 2)
                    if len(bullets2) < 1:
                        bullets2.append(projectile2(px2, py2, 4, (255,255,255), direction2))




        for bullet in bullets[:]:
            bullet.move()
            window_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
            if not window_rect.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)):
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet)) #if off the screen, delete bullet 

            #------------------------FOR THE FIRST TANK -- THE CONDITIONS OF THIS IF STATEMENTS IS WHERE I BELIEVE THE BUG IS OCCURRING AND WHERE IT MUST BE RESOLVED----------#
            #######################################################################################################################################
            #######################################################################################################################################
            ##################################################################################################################################################

            if barrier.collidepoint((bullet.x + 3, bullet.y + 3)) or barrier2.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier3.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier4.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier5.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier6.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier7.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier8.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier9.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier10.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier11.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier12.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier13.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier14.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier15.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier16.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier17.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier18.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier19.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier20.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier21.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier22.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier23.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier24.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier25.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier26.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier27.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier28.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier28.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier29.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier30.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier31.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier32.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier33.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier34.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier35.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier35.collidepoint((bullet.x,bullet.y)):
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet)) #if it touches a wall, delete bullet 

            #######################################################################################################################################
            #######################################################################################################################################
            ##################################################################################################################################################

            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < tank2.hitbox[1] + tank2.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > tank2.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > tank2.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < tank2.hitbox[0] + tank2.hitbox[2]:
                    hCounter1 += 1
                    tank2.x, tank2.y = random.randint(1,475), random.randint(20,475)
                    tank.x, tank.y = random.randint(1,475), random.randint(20,475)
                    tank2.hit(screen)
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

        for bullet in bullets2[:]:
            bullet.move()
            window_rect2 = pygame.Rect(0,0, screenWidth, screenHeight)
            if not window_rect2.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)):
                bullets2.pop(bullets2.index(bullet))
            if bullet.y - bullet.radius < tank.hitbox[1] + tank.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.radius > tank.hitbox[1]:
                if bullet.x + bullet.radius > tank.hitbox[0] and bullet.x - bullet.radius < tank.hitbox[0] + tank.hitbox[2]:
                    hCounter2 += 1
                    tank2.x, tank2.y = random.randint(1,475), random.randint(20,475)
                    tank.x, tank.y = random.randint(1,475), random.randint(20,475)                
                    tank.hit() 
                    bullets2.pop(bullets2.index(bullet))
           #------------------------FOR THE SECOND TANK -- THE CONDITIONS OF THIS IF STATEMENTS IS WHERE I BELIEVE THE BUG IS OCCURRING AND WHERE IT MUST BE RESOLVED----------#
            #######################################################################################################################################
            #######################################################################################################################################
            ##################################################################################################################################################

            if barrier.collidepoint((bullet.x + 3, bullet.y + 3)) or barrier2.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier3.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier4.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier5.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier6.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier7.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier8.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier9.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier10.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier11.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier12.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier13.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier14.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier15.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier16.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier17.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier18.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier19.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier20.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier21.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier22.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier23.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier24.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier25.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier26.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier27.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier28.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier28.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier29.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier30.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier31.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier32.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier33.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier34.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier35.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)) or barrier36.collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y)):
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
```

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please only post the relevant portions of the code that you are having problems with

Comment: @Iain Shelvington is this better? I did it because I thought most information was necessary to establish all information about coordinates.

Comment: Could it be that the bullet is one side of the barrier on the first tick and then is on the other side of the barrier on the second tick? If this is the case then there would not be a tick when the bullet collided with the barrier

Comment: Perhaps but I don't want the velocity of the bullet to be any slower than it is. How would that be amended otherwise?

Comment: There is an answer in this question that may help, it's fairly complicated though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40431402/line-collision-in-pygame

Comment: Never mind, thanks for your help. The issue was indeed in the clock ticks and I amended it by doubling the clock.tick to 60, then halving the velocity of the bullets so that the program was able to catch it in its ticks before it passed through the maze walls. The actual speed of the bullet travelling across the screen stayed the exact same. Once again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the velocity of the bullets as it was too fast for the program to catch in its tick, which essentially allowed the bullet to make its way through the maze wall.

One can adjust the clock to 60 frames per second, as so:

`clock.tick(60)`

Then in the projectile class, or wherever one is determining the velocity of the bullet--that must be adjusted to the clock rate.

If your velocity was 8 with the demonstrated clock rate of 30, then adjust the clock rate to 60, half that velocity or thereabout to even the ratio of speed to what you wanted it as. In my case:

```
def __init__(self,x, y, radius, color, direction): 
    #ESTABLISH ALL DIMENSIONS
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.radius = radius
    self.color = color
    self.direction = direction
    self.vel = 5 #if it was previously 8 with a clock tick of 30.
```

The program should be able to catch the bullet in its ticks and stop it before it crosses through the wall. And the relative speed of the bullet moving across the screen should stay the same - remember to adjust the velocity of other moving objects accordingly too, such as the sprites.