# Deciding which colliding segment to use as impact vector for reflection

Tags: python, collision-detection, game-physics, vector-graphics, vectormath

### Problem

I´m working on a simple OpenGL project. My goal is to correctly reflect an object that has a force on it, off of an impacted object.

To do this, I am using the shape´s line segments (segment is two points that make up a line), for collision detection. The segments of a square would for example be:

```py
self.segments = [
            Segment2D(self.bottom_left, self.bottom_right),  # Bottom side
            Segment2D(self.bottom_right, self.top_right),  # Right side
            Segment2D(self.top_right, self.top_left),  # Top side
            Segment2D(self.top_left, self.bottom_left)  # Left side
        ]
```

The detection works by checking if any of the object's segments are intersecting with an external object's segments. I am using a method explained in geeksforgeeks: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/

To calculate the reflection I am using the formula r=d−2(d⋅n)n 
[image]

- d : The force vector
- b : The impacted surface vector
- n : the normalized (unit vector) normal vector 90degrees on the impacted surface
- r : The reflection vector of the force vector

However; After finding that an object is colliding with another object, a problem arises with finding this reflection vector.

[image]

When two squares collide for example (the only shape I've implemented), the collision detection will sometimes detect collision on two segments. Since I do not know how I should choose which one to use as the impacted segment the reflection will sometimes be in the wrong direction.

### Question

How can I decide which segment of the green ones in the image should be used as the impact vector for the reflection?

**Edit:** 
I have now implemented the solution Blindman67 suggested. The collision detection, (deciding which side to collide) seems to work in about 80% of cases. The square sometimes still reflects in the wrong direction when colliding close to a corner. I am not sure whether this is a bug of mine or the given solution.

I have been unable to resolve the issue.

Also the checks no longer hold when the impacted square is swallowed on both sides, making the impacted lines parallel to each other.

This is the logic I've come up with:

```py
def rect_rect_collision(self, other, force: Vector2D, segments: List[Segment2D]) -> Segment2D:
        """
        Returns the segment that is the most correct one for collision
        :param other: Colliding RigidBody
        :param force: The force applied on the object
        :param segments: The segments that were detected as colliding by the general detection
        :return: The correct collision segment
        """
        if segments[0].angle() == segments[1].angle():
            # TODO: decide which to collide of the remaining 2
            raise Exception("Lines are parallel")

        # Shared corner of the impacted segments
        common_corner = RigidRect2D.get_common_corner(segments[0], segments[1])
        E: Point2D = self.add_width_height_relative_to_center(common_corner, other.shape.center)
        # Segment 0 is EF
        seg_0_other = segments[0].p1 if segments[0].p2 == common_corner else segments[0].p2
        F: Point2D = self.add_width_height_relative_to_center(seg_0_other, other.shape.center)
        # Segment 1 is EJ
        seg_1_other = segments[1].p1 if segments[1].p2 == common_corner else segments[1].p2
        J: Point2D = self.add_width_height_relative_to_center(seg_1_other, other.shape.center)

        A: Point2D = self.shape.center
        ABx: float = force.x
        ABy: float = force.y
        uu = ABx * (A.y - E.y) - ABy * (A.x - E.x)

        EFx = F.x - E.x
        EFy = F.y - E.y
        c = ABx * EFy - ABy * EFx
        if c != 0:
            u = uu / c
            print("U - EF: ", u)
            if 0 <= u <= 1:
                # Hits line E-F
                return segments[0]

        EJx = J.x - E.x
        EJy = J.y - E.y
        c = ABx * EJy - ABy * EJx
        if c != 0:
            u = uu / c
            print("U - EJ: ", u)
            if 0 <= u <= 1:
                # Hits line E-J
                return segments[1]

        raise Exception("Returned no segment from the collision detection")

    @staticmethod
    def get_common_corner(segment1: Segment2D, segment2: Segment2D):
        if segment1.has_point(segment2.p1):
            return segment2.p1
        if segment1.has_point(segment2.p2):
            return segment2.p2
        print(segment1)
        print(segment2)
        raise Exception("No common corner")

    def add_width_height_relative_to_center(self, point: Point2D, center: Point2D) -> Point2D:
        newPoint = Point2D(point.x, point.y)
        if newPoint.y >= center.y:
            newPoint.y += self.shape.height / 2
        else:
            newPoint.y -= self.shape.height / 2

        if newPoint.x >= center.x:
            newPoint.x += self.shape.width / 2
        else:
            newPoint.x -= self.shape.width / 2

        return newPoint
```

Here's an image depicting the incorrect impact vector that the reflection method received from the rect_rect_collision method:
[image: incorrect_impact vector]

The green outlines are the rigidBodies that are collidable, the red arrow is the force vector's direction BEFORE the reflection. After the reflection is calculated, the reflection will be in the incorrect direction.

Comment: Well, the correct impact side seems to overlap more in the moving square, so you can just compare the two squares' x and y coordinates to distinguish that. Still, it's possible that they're equally distance in x and y when it hits a corner, how do you want to reflect it, then?

Comment: How would I go about figuring that out without assuming both objects to be a square? If it impacts in a corner point I would assume the reflection to go in the direction of the greater constant of the force, but haven't thought much about it as I'm more concerned with the larger problem.

Comment: Yeah that's a much tougher problem, and I can't even pinpoint the exact task. See, you could generalize to polygons because that has straight sides, but what about round surfaces like circles or semicircles? It's pretty complex

Comment: I read somewhere that all graphic shapes are made up of triangles, so even a circle is just a polygon with very many edges so I think the logic would still be the same

Comment: Well, that's for surfaces of 3D objects. And even then, I think they usually cheaply model collision with spheres (so two things collide if they're just close enough) or hitboxes (so a collision happens when you get into a zone of 3D space).

Answer (score 2):

Using the following illustration.

[image]

The box moves along the vector A-B.
Calculate the intercepts between A-B and E-F and E-J as units along E-F, or E-J
The point of intercept C will in the illustration be between lines A-B and E-J

```
ABx = B.x - A.x
ABy = B.y - A.y
uu = ABx * (A.y - E.y) - ABy * (A.x - E.x)

EFx = F.x - E.x
EFy = F.y - E.y
c = ABx * EFy - ABy * EFx
if (c !== 0) {
    u = uu / c
    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
        // hits line E-F
    }
}

EJx = J.x - E.x
EJy = J.y - E.y
c = ABx * EJy - ABy * EJx
if (c !== 0) {
    u = uu / c
    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
        // hits line E-J
    }
}
```

If the boxes are axis aligned AABB then you can simplify by canceling out zeros

```
ABx = B.x - A.x
ABy = B.y - A.y
uu = ABx * (A.y - E.y) - ABy * (A.x - E.x)

c = -ABy * (F.x - E.x)  
if (c !== 0) {
    u = uu / c
    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
        // hits line E-F
    }
}

c = ABx * (J.y - E.y) 
if (c !== 0) {
    u = uu / c
    if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
        // hits line E-J
    }
}
```

**Note** that point E represent the common corner as the test is only between the two sides you wish to test. You will never need to test more than two sides.

Comment: Ok so in conclusion, I cannot determine the impact point without pre-determining the shape of both objects. So after I detect a collision of two squares I would apply the method you describe to find the side/point of impact?

Comment: @Hauksson Yes you must know both shapes. For the best results you use this to detect collision. Why? End point B may be outside 2nd box though AB still intercepted 1 or more of  lines EF, FG, GJ, or JE. Example 1st box crosses a corner or moves over 2nd box. If the point B is outside then calc u for AB for each edge eg for edge EF `uu = (F.x - E.x) * (A.y - E.y) - (F.y - E.y * (A.x - E.x)`  and `u = uu /c` then point of intercept is the edge that gives the lowest u if u is  `0<=u<=1`. You then don't need to calc u in terms of edge.

Comment: I  have to do this collision detection before every move then. I assume I would also have to introduce time as a variable in the force in order to find the collision point C to do the reflection from the correct position... Oof, I have never done any physics engine related programming before so this is quite a task

Comment: Because if I just do the reflection in the next frame then the object might have moved through the other one before the reflection is done.

Comment: @Hauksson You can use a simple model if you ensure no edge cases or accept that some solutions are not perfect. My answer is for a problem that involves only 2 boxes. If you add 1 more then it becomes possible for there to be < infinite collisions over time u `0 < u <= 1` . One must check for earliest collision (smallest u) between box & all boxes, calc new pos and vec at collision time u then from that time repeat for box and all boxes until u > 1.  If only one box moves and speed is less than min size of other boxes then at most there are 2 collisions per frame.

Comment: You don't need the rotation of the square if it is not axis aligned in the collision check? Could you tell me the name of this detection method, so I can read it up somewhere

Comment: I also started to look into the Separating Axis Theorem (SAT) but was unable to find information on how to find the intersecting segment

Comment: @Hauksson SAT is a hack as it only detects collisions when shapes at time 1 overlap. It can provide an estimate of which edges collided first based on dist from edges (to ensure no overlap at time 1 as solutions that result in overlap MUST!!! be avoided). Sorry there is no name (that I know) as there are so many variations.

Comment: Ok great thank you! I will try to implement your method and will come back and choose your answer if all goes well

Comment: If the rectangle is rotated, do I have to be concerned about what corner is E, F, J,  G? I currently initialize a rectangle with topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright corner points, but if the rectangle is rotated the points might no longer correspond to that

Comment: @Hauksson it is the line segments that matter. Except for the second snippet which assumes the line segment EF has 0 y component and the line segment EJ has 0 x component. It would be best to normalize all boxes so that they are referenced from top left . This [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40436886/3877726) uses another method (line slope) to find intercepts. And [tile based AABB intercepts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920237/3877726) uses yet another method. How best to solve will depend on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I've now implemented your solution and the collisions close to corners seem to be incorrect in some cases. I updated my post with the code I implemented

Answer (score 0):

The accurate way to do this is to treat objects in motion as a function of time.

Currently, you do a full update's worth of motion, then check if the objects overlap:

```
(x, y) := (x+dx, y+dy)
```

Instead, you can treat the object's position as a function of time (from the previous  frame to new one).  This makes the output of the collision logic also a function of time:  starting at "no" collision (as you have already checked the previous frame), and possibly changing to "yes" before the end of the update period.

```
pos(t) = (x+t*dx, y+t*dy)  # for t in [0..1]
```

Solving for earliest collision point should also let you determine which side the collision is on:  each side will have a collision condition, and the first one that fails is the one that is hit.  In addition, this method avoids the case where your objects are moving so fast that they can pass through each other.

Comment: If I have to check all positions between t0 and t1 for the earliest collision, wouldn't the coordinate precision of the program have to be defined since the possible positions would otherwise be infinite? Or how would a collision condition look like?

Comment: I think what you are talking about in the second paragraph would be raytracing?

Comment: It is sort of like 2D raytracing, yes.  The main difference from basic raytracing is that you need to take into account the shape of both objects, not just the target.